# How to translate SQL inner join with like clause to dplyr workflow?

Tags: mysql, r, dplyr, tidyverse, dbplyr

I have three mySQL database tables 1-3. My goal is to perform some left and inner join operations on these tables using R dplyr. I am attempting to translate my original SQL code to dplyr workflow using dbplyr in R. Part of my original SQL query looks like this:

`INNER JOIN table3 ON tabl1.well = table3.well AND table2.plex LIKE table3.set`

My R code so far looks like:

```
library(RMySQL)
library(dbplyr)
library(dplyr)

t1 <- tbl(con,'table1')
t2 <- tbl(con,'table2')
t3 <- tbl(con,'table3')
st <- select(t2,set) %>% filter(!duplicated(set))

t1 %>% left_join(t2,.,by=c('d_id'='p_id') %>%
    inner_join(t3,by='well') %>%
    filter(plex %in% st) %>%      # this part is wrong!!
    collect()
```

When the above R code is run, the results are different from the SQL query. I would like to know what is the right way to translate the inner join part of SQL query to the dplyr syntax in R. A simple inner_join on two columns is quite straigtforward with dplyr. But I am having hard time translating the part with AND and LIKE clause to dplyr lingo. Unfortunately I don't have any replicable data for this example.

Comment: Your `filter` is the right idea, but `%in%` is the wrong function. Generally SQL like uses wildcards `%` and `_` for specific behavior. If those are included in your data, they will take some work to translate. I don't know how to correct your code without any sample data. Maybe you can make up a few fake rows to share? Doesn't have to be real data, but a few lines of sample input and desired output would make this an answerable question.

Answer (score 1):

`dbplyr` will preserve infix functions as they are.  In other words you can use the `%like%` operator as the equivalent of the SQL LIKE.  You can then use the same wild cards characters, so something like: `filter(name %like% "%text%")` should work